# CSV to D3: summing over values for multiple links

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm drawing a network graph on D3 with data that looks like this:

target  source  value

```
Baird   JON CARLSON 100    
Baird   JASON CONRAD    100    
Baird   JASON CONRAD    100    
Baird   JASON CONRAD    100    
Baird   JANET ESKRIDGE  100    
Baird   LINDA GARNER MULLIN 100    
Baird   JAMES HARRIS    100
```

...etc.

The three "Baird | JASON CONRAD | 100" rows are not duplicates; I want D3 to sum over the individuals to give "Baird | JASON CONRAD | 300" before it inputs the link.

I'm new to JS and D3 and don't really have a clue how I'd go about that, but here's your classic csv import function in question:

```
d3.csv("xxx.csv", function(error, links) {

var nodes = {};

links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || 
      (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] ||
      (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
    link.value = +link.value;
});

force

  .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
  .links(links)
  .start()
```

**EDIT**

I used nest() to sum the values up, but now I've no idea how to input the result into usable links and nodes arrays for force().

Any ideas? This is my nest() code:

```
var nested_links = d3.nest()  
    .key(function(link) { return link.source; })  
    .key(function(link) { return link.target; })  
    .rollup(function(link) { 
        return d3.sum(link, function(l) { return l.value; });  
    }).entries(links);
```

Comment: Start by checking out [`d3.nest()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_nest), which gives you a way to group the duplicates and calculate their totals (using nest's `rollup()` function).

Comment: You don't need to use `forEach()`, you can use `map()` after the `nest()`. Check my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @meetamit said you can use `d3.nest()` for this task.

**How `d3.nest()` works?**

if you have

```
var data = [
    ["Baird JON CARLSON", 100],
    ["Baird JASON CONRAD", 100],
    ["Baird JASON CONRAD", 100],
    ["Baird JASON CONRAD", 100],
    ["Baird JANET ESKRIDGE", 100],
    ["Baird LINDA GARNER MULLIN", 100],
    ["Baird JAMES HARRIS", 100]
];
```

and execute

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
                    .key(function(d) {
                        return d[0];
                    })
                    .entries(data);
```

`nested_data` will be something like this

```
[{
    "key":"Baird JON CARLSON",
    "values":[
        ["Baird JON CARLSON",100]
    ]
 },{
     "key":"Baird JASON CONRAD",
     "values":[
        ["Baird JASON CONRAD",100],
        ["Baird JASON CONRAD",100],
        ["Baird JASON CONRAD",100]
     ]
 },{...
}]
```

with Javascript normaly you can use `Array.reduce()` for reduce the array to the sum of the values, but with `D3js` the best option is use `d3.nest().rollup()`. `D3js`has too a helper to reduce an `Array()` to a sum of the returned value and if you have

```
var values = [
    ["Baird JASON CONRAD",100],
    ["Baird JASON CONRAD",100],
    ["Baird JASON CONRAD",100]
];
```

then you can make

```
 var sum = d3.sum(values, function(d) {
               return parseFloat(d[1]);
           });
```

and `sum` will be `300`. Glueing all this will be

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
                    .key(function(d) {
                        return d[0];
                    })
                    .rollup(function(leaves) {
                        return d3.sum(leaves, function(d) {
                            return parseFloat(d[1]);
                        });
                    })
                    .entries(data);
```

after that you'll have on `nested_data` something like this

```
[{
    "key":"Baird JON CARLSON",
    "values": 100
 },{
    "key":"Baird JASON CONRAD",
    "values": 300
 },{
    "key":"Baird JANET ESKRIDGE",
    "values": 100
 },{
    "key":"Baird LINDA GARNER MULLIN",
    "values": 100
 },{
   "key":"Baird JAMES HARRIS",
   "values": 100
}]
```

Check [my Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jkutianski/jf6BK/)

To create your link array as you need it, you've to map the keys and values to the correct position on the array. Take on care that if you use 2 key function you will finish with a double nested object.

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
                    .key(function(d) {
                        return [d[0],d[1]];
                    })
                    .rollup(function(leaves) {
                        return d3.sum(leaves, function(d) {
                            return parseFloat(d[2]);
                        });
                    })
                    .entries(data)
                    .map( function (d) {
                        var val = d.key.split(',');
                        return {source: val[0], target: val[1], value: d.values};
                    });
```

Check [my Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jkutianski/a4sUJ/)

Comment: OK, but then what? Now the keys are strings and I can't derive which part of it is the source and which is the target... I've edited in my implementation of nest() into my original question. But now, I'm not sure how to translate that into links and nodes usable for force(). Could you help me?